# Finding a limit of a floor function.

Tags: real-analysis

Find the limit of:
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{a}\cdot\lfloor\frac{b}{x}\rfloor$ ($a,b>0$)

Is the following solution correct?
$\frac{x}{a}(\frac{b}{x}-1)\leq \frac{x}{a}\cdot\lfloor\frac{b}{x}\rfloor\leq \frac{xb}{ax}$
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{a}(\frac{b}{x}-1)=\frac{b}{a}$
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{xb}{ax}=\frac{b}{a}$
And using the squeeze theorem, I get
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{a}\cdot\lfloor\frac{b}{x}\rfloor=\frac{b}{a}$

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively,

$$\frac xa\left\lfloor\frac bx\right\rfloor=\frac xa\frac bx-\frac xa\left\{\frac bx\right\}$$

where the braces denote the fractional part.

The first term obviously tends to $\dfrac ba$, while the second vanishes (the fractional part is bounded).

---

**Intuitive explanation:**

The parameter $a$ is inessential and WLOG $a=1$. Then with $x=10^{-k}$

$$10^{-k}\lfloor10^kb\rfloor$$

represents the number $b$ truncated to $k$ decimals. Hence this tends to $b$.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

As $\left\lfloor\dfrac bx\right\rfloor=\dfrac bx+O(1)$, the limit is that of $\dfrac xa\dfrac bx$.

Comment: @miracle173: asymptotically equal. But I have rewritten once again.

Comment: I think this does not work, O(1) is about increasing x and has nothing to do with x->0.

Comment: @miracle173: hehe, we are talking about $b/x$, which goes to infinity.

Comment: then you have invented a completely new notation today, at least a completely new interpretation of a traditional notation.  Congratulations.

Comment: @miracle173: not at all. What I wrote is equivalent to $\lfloor t\rfloor=t+O(1)$ for $t\to\infty$. It was never said that the argument of the function under $O$ *must* be written $x$.